# Javascript count down not updating

Tags: javascript

I am writing a redirect page for my website. And on it, I am using javascript to countdown the time before redirect happens.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>We have moved to a new location</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="text-align: center;margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;font-size: 72px"><b>We have moved to a new location!</b></h1>
<p style="font-size: 36px; text-align: center; margin-right: auto; margin-left:auto;">You will be redirected to our new website in <span id="timer"></span> or you can click <a href="">here</a> to redirect manually.
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = 10;

    function countdown(time) {
        if (time == 0) {
            window.location.href = "http://cs221.cs.usfca.edu/";
        }
        time = time - 1;
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = time;
    }
    setInterval(countdown, 1000, document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML);
})
</script>
</html>
```

I have a JSFiddle of it here: https://jsfiddle.net/vhyw57um/13/

I have tried to put 10 in the span but it was causing the same problem. It would decrement the timer by 1 then just gets caught in a loop. I feel like it's an easy bug that I'm just missing here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML` is performed exactly once, when `setInterval` is executed - it is not performed for each callback - move `document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML` to `var time = document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML` inside the `countdown` function instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setInternval` is being set with the values:

```
 setInterval(countdown, 1000, 10);
```

The `document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML` is evaluated once and only once, not every time the `setInterval()` is run.

In other words, it is not redetermining what `document.getElementById('timer')` contains. It did that already when the function was called. That is why the value only decrements to 9 because it always starts as 10.

Answer (score 0):

please check my solution :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = 10;
        var time = 10;
        function countdown() {


            if (time == 0) {
                window.location.href = "http://cs221.cs.usfca.edu/";
            }
            time = time - 1;
            document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = time;
        }
        setInterval(countdown, 1000);
    })
</script>
```